# Apt-get update Failed to Fetch while setting proxy

Tags: apt

I realize that there are many "failed to fetch" questions asked before, but neither seems to resolve my issue.

This is what I get after typing `export http_proxy=http://198.23.143.4:8080`
then `sudo apt-get update`

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 11.10 (not an upgrade)

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                             

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease                     

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease                   

Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease                      

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                               
  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 198.23.143.4:8080:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on errors you have provided it seems that your sever can not establish TCP connection to the proxy server.

Can you telnet (establish TCP connection) to port 8080 at 198.23.143.4?

```
telnet 198.23.143.4 8080
```

Comment: No, I could not. This is what I got:   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: "connection refused" may suggests that the proxy server is down **or** it is configured to reject connections from your IP address.

Comment: So, what can I do now? And, how about those "Failed to fetch" files -- are those a result of the TCP issue?

Comment: Almost for sure.

Comment: Thanks, Andrzej. Will change the proxy, and see what happens.